# how to run docker on apple silicon (m1)

Tags: docker, apple-m1

I'v installed docker by homebrew on Mac with m1 cpu. But it doesn't run. It tells me that I need to use intel cpu. But on Docker site I see that docker should run. How to fix that?

```
Incompatible CPU detected

We are sorry, but your hardware is incompatible with Docker Desktop.

This version of Docker Desktop requires an Intel processor.

To learn more about this issue see:
```

Comment: This will help : https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/apple-m1/

Comment: i'v seen this but I doesn't see here anything helpful

Comment: So watch this video as it installing docker on M1 Chip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wsg7wrTbBRk

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Docker Desktop RC3 is available at https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/apple-m1/

See the download link at the top. This is a link to DMG file. Install it and you're good to go.

I am using it since 2 months.

**Update, Nov 8, 2021**

Updating it late, but now Docker Desktop for M1 is available (earlier it was preview version). Docker Desktop for M1 is now fully supported and can be downloaded at - https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop

Comment: `softwareupdate --install-rosetta` and `brew install --cask docker` worked for me.

Comment: @LauriElias That installs x86 docker and runs it on Rosetta, which does work but is probably not what you want. Instead, download Docker from the website manually.

Comment: OK, so, it is not possible to install the ARM Docker version (Apple Silicon) with Homebrew (as of the time of this writing this post). I will post the instructions for doing it without brew below.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply download the docker desktop for the Mac with apple silicon and replace the old one while installing it

Answer (score -1):

Here are the instructions to install Docker Desktop on Apple Silicon  (ARM 64 processor, like Mac Studio, M1 Max). The demo will be part of Getting Started with Concourse CI, a course that will be released on Pluralsight in the next 3 to 5 weeks. See module 3 and find the clip for installing Concourse - the Docker installation will be part of it. Anyhow, here are the commands that you can put in a script, make it executable and run it. Optionally, before you run it, uncomment the commands that move the .dmg file to the trash. I've also included the the "uninstall" command.

```
wget https://desktop.docker.com/mac/main/arm64/Docker.dmg
sudo hdiutil attach Docker.dmg
sudo /Volumes/Docker/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/install
sudo hdiutil detach /Volumes/Docker

### Move Docker.dmg to the recycle bin
# trash Docker.dmg
### Empty the trash
# trash -e 

### Uninstall Docker
# /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/uninstall
# trash /Applications/Docker.app
```

Comment: This does nothing to answer the question, which pertains to an "Invalid CPU" error